# why is not working? Math.pow in Java

Tags: java

my professor told us to make a java program to do exponents. so i try to write this code:

```
System.Out.PrintLn("Enter a number/integer to do raise to a power: ");
Scanner MyScanner = new Scanner(System.In);
int Integer = MyScanner.NextInt();

System.Out.PrintLn("Enter an exponential power: ");
Scanner MyScanner1 = new Scanner(System.In);
int Power = MyScanner1.NextInt();

int Answer=Math.pow(Integer, Power);

System.Out.PrintLn(Integer + "^" + Power + "=" + Answer);
```

But it gives me an error :(

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

But where is my code wrong?? I think the structure is all correct.

**Edit:**

I am using Eclipse ide.

Comment: It's impossible that the above code throws such an exception, since it doesn't even compile. If you want us to explain why your code throws a given exception, show us the real, compiling code, and provide the full stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 3):

Java is *case sensitive*, you have numerous case typos, for example, replace

```
System.Out.PrintLn("Enter a number/integer to do raise to a power: ");
```

with

```
System.out.println("Enter a number/integer to do raise to a power: ");
```

Also, always consult the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) if unsure of method names, you need:

```
MyScanner.nextInt();
```

You havent provided any information as to why the `NoClassDefFoundError` is occurring. Are you attempting to run the application *without* a successful compilation first?

Aside: Java naming conventions indicate that variables start with a *lowercase* letter which would make `MyScanner` `myScanner`.